# wso2 Gov Registry indexing looping

Tags: indexing, wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

I created a custom RXT asset to register my own objects. The system works fine when I add and browse objects.

But if I delete an object instance using the Management Console by `Resources/Browse`, browse to `/system/governance/[objects]/[object]`, and try and create a new one, the system starts looping and displays the message:

> "Please wait while the asset is being indexing"

This message does not disappear. From this start point, all new objects do not show in publisher and store, but do exist in `/system/governance/[objects]/[object]`.

Comment: which version of GREG is used?

Comment: WSO2 Governance Registry ver 5.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Please do a re-indexing resources**

Follow the steps below to re-index the resources.

1. Delete the /solr/ directory.
2. Change the name  (e.g.  lastaccesstime to lastaccesstime_1)  of the file  in the registry which tracks the last access time of indexing the resources, by changing the value of the  ***lastAccessTimeLocation***  property in the  /repositiry/conf/registry.xml  file as follows.

   /_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime_1
3. Restart the G-Reg server and wait for around 30 minutes. This time duration depends on number of resources that are there in the registry.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromaPreviousRelease-Re-indexingresources